# Is there a way to update a secondary attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm currently working on a Ruby on Rails (v5.2) project for recording attendances at sports clubs. Each Student belongs to a payment_plan and each payment_plan has a classes_amount. Classes_amount is the number of classes a student is able to attend before making another payment. Each student has a classes_remaining column to keep track of this. It automatically decreases after each attendance, and increases each time they make a payment.

I want to automatically update the student's classes_remaining attribute when I change their payment_plan. E.g. if a student wanted to change from payment_plan A (5 classes), to payment_plan B (10 classes) I'd want their classes_remaining attribute to increase by 10. At the moment when I assign a student to a new payment plan, their classes_remaining value stays at nil.

This is what I currently have in my update method:

```
def update
    @student = current_club.students.find_by(id: params[:id])
    classes_amount = @student.payment_plan.classes_amount
    logger.debug "Classes amount is currently: #{classes_amount}"
    if classes_amount.present?
        if @student.classes_remaining.present?
            @student.classes_remaining = @student.classes_remaining + classes_amount
        else
            @student.classes_remaining = classes_amount
        end
    else
        @student.classes_remaining = nil
    end
    if @student.update_attributes(student_params)
        flash[:success] = "Student details updated"
        redirect_to @student
    else
        @activities = current_club.activities.all
        render 'edit'
    end
end
```

There is one payment_plan this has no classes_amount, hence the `if classes_amount.present?` line.
My debug message shows `Classes amount is currently:`

How can I automatically update the student's classes_remaining column when their payment_plan changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably easiest to use the ActiveModel::Dirty, https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

You just need to add this line to your student model:

```
## app/models/student.rb

class Student << ApplicationBase
  include ActiveModel::Dirty
  ...
  ...
end
```

This gives you access to the following methods:

```
student.payment_plan_id_changed?
student.payment_plan_id_changed?(from: 1, to: 2)
```

These will return true or false assuming the record has yet to be saved. Which means in your model you can now do:

```
## app/models/student.rb

class Student << ApplicationBase
  include ActiveModel::Dirty
  define_attribute_methods :payment_plan_id

  before_save :handle_payment_plan_changes!

  private

  def handle_payment_plan_changes!
    return unless payment_plan_id_changed?

    if payment_plan_id_changed?(from: 1, to: 2)
      classes_remaining += 5
    elsif payment_plan_id_changed?(from: 2, to: 1)
      classes_remaining -= 5
    end
  end
end
```

It's worth noting that this before_save will fire every time a student is saved so ensure you want this behaviour on every save. If this is an issue you can always manually call `handle_payment_plan_changes` from your controller before saving (after moving the method out of the private section).

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution worked, HOWEVER I did have to remove `:payment_plan_id` from `define_attribute_methods :payment_plan_id` in the model because it was throwing an incorrect number of arguments error (got 1 expected 0). Once I removed that it worked perfectly.